# find the sum of all integers in the range [1, n] that are divisible by 3, 5, or 7 using multithread basics in java

Tags: java, multithreading

explanation of the question:
you must write a multithreaded program that finds all
integers in the range [1, n] that are divisible by 3, 5, or 7. Return the
sum of all unique integers as your answer.
Note that an integer such as 15 (which is a multiple of 3 and 5) is only
counted once.
The Positive integer n > 0 is given to you as input. Create as many threads as
you need to solve the problem. You can use a Thread Pool for bonus points.

```
Example:
Input: n = 10
Output: sum = 40
Explanation: Numbers in the range [1, 10] that are divisible by 3, 5, or 7 are:
3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10. The sum of these numbers is 40.
```

My solution and problem that I faced:
in this program I created three threads each for finding the integers that are divided by 3,5 and 7 separately then it will store them all in the dividends array list and by the following code it will remove the repeated ones in the array list:

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(dividends);
    dividends.clear();
    dividends.addAll(set);
```

I used some test cases that were provided by our teacher and the problem is that in the testcases that n=1000 and n=76293 sum won't show the amount that was expected:

```
n=1000
expected sum:272066
actual sum:247377
```

and the other problem is that the actual sum keeps changing every time I run the testcase.
can someone tell me what the problem of my code is and how I can fix it

my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FindMultiples
{

public static ArrayList<Integer> dividends = new ArrayList<>();
public static int temp = 0;
public static synchronized void increment(){
    dividends.add(temp);
}
public static class thread implements Runnable{

    public int divisor;
    public int n;

    public thread(int n , int divisor){
        this.n=n;
        this.divisor=divisor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
            if (i%divisor==0){
                temp=i;
                increment();
            }
        }
    }
}

public int getSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new thread(n,3));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new thread(n,7));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new thread(n,5));
    
    thread3.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread1.start();
    try {
        thread3.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread1.join();
    }catch (InterruptedException e){

    }
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(dividends);
    dividends.clear();
    dividends.addAll(set);

    for (int i : dividends){
        sum+=i;
    }

    return sum;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
}
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be iterating through 1 to n in unit steps since 'most' of the values will not be selected.  I'd just generate the values that will match - e.g. `for (i=divisor; i<=n; i+=divisor) storeResult(i)`. I'd have one thread per unique divisor 3,5,7. Eliminate duplicates as before.

Comment: my understanding of "multithreaded program that finds all integers in the range [1, n] that are divisible by 3, 5, or 7" is: you need write program using something like: int stream > range > parallel > filter > sum. That would be the only solution which actually makes sense.

Comment: `IntStream.range(1, n).parallel().filter(i -> i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0).sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your main problem is that you are synchronizing the increment() method, and not synchronizing the temp variable.
While one thread is trying to execute the increment() method, the second thread is changing the value of the temp variable. Run your code in debug and check it out.

It's better to send the value directly to increment() than store it in temp.
See my edited code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class FindMultiples
{

  public static ArrayList<Integer> dividends = new ArrayList<>();
  public static synchronized void increment(int temp){
     dividends.add(temp);
  }
  
  public static class MyThread implements Runnable{

    public int divisor;
    public int n;

    public MyThread(int n , int divisor){
        this.n=n;
        this.divisor=divisor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
            if (i%divisor==0){
                increment(i);
            }
        }
    }
  }

  public int getSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyThread(n,3));
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(new MyThread(n,7));
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(new MyThread(n,5));

    thread3.start();
    thread2.start();
    thread1.start();
    try {
        thread3.join();
        thread2.join();
        thread1.join();
    }catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>(dividends);
    dividends.clear();
    dividends.addAll(set);

    for (int i : dividends){
        sum+=i;
    }

    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindMultiples findMultiples = new FindMultiples();
    System.out.println(findMultiples.getSum(1000));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, I believe solution below is the most optimal, cause it is just an arithmetic formula:

```java
BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Long> sumDivInRange = (to, div) -> {
    int first = (1 / div) * div;
    int last = (to / div) * div;

    return ((long) first + last) * ((last - first) / div + 1) / 2;
};

int n = 100000000;

// not sure we need parallel that
return sumDivInRange.apply(n, 3)
        + sumDivInRange.apply(n, 5)
        + sumDivInRange.apply(n, 7)
        - sumDivInRange.apply(n, 15)
        - sumDivInRange.apply(n, 21)
        - sumDivInRange.apply(n, 35)
        + sumDivInRange.apply(n, 105);
```

Comment: yes, that is quickest so far :)

Comment: This solution requires human-assisted step to properly count once each integer; if that is the case, since 3,4,7 are coprime, the result is just :sumDivInRange.apply(n, 1) - sumDivInRange.apply(n, 105)

Comment: the magic numbers are just LCMs of singles, pairs, triplets, etc, so, technically no human interaction required, however I agree that in common case it is not a formula from math perspective because the amount algo steps depends on the size of input.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the shared variable `temp` which is expected to hold the same value across several statements.

```
public static int temp = 0;
public static synchronized void increment() {
    dividends.add(temp);
}
```

In each thread:

```
temp=i;
increment();
```

So if thread1 sets 'temp', it can be changed by another thread before thread1 gets to use it in increment.

But it's not necessary anyway.

```
public static synchronized void increment(int x) {
    dividends.add(X);
}
```

then

```
increment(i);
```

Other answers talk about eliminating unnecessary static, which is valid design criticism, but that in itself does not fix your 'temp' problem.  Even a non-static 'temp' is still shared across threads - there's one instance of FindMultiples shared by all of the thread instances.

This answer addresses the question of why you're getting variable results.  In comments I've noted that efficiency can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The main solution to your problem is to lose `static` everywhere. Never use `static` unless you have a very good reason to. In this case, you do not. Generally speaking, it will be a few years of programming in Java before you will encounter your first situation where you may legitimately use `static`. Until then, just don't.

As a bonus thought, you could perhaps greatly reduce the amount of work you have to do by not creating a thread for each divisor and instead creating threads for different ranges of integers that you want to process. So, for example, for `n = 1000` you might create two threads, one that will process numbers from 1 to 500 and another that will process numbers from 501 to 1000. This way, each thread is guaranteed to yield numbers that will not be yielded by the other thread.

Comment: Better yet, just generate the right numbers instead of looking for them. We know in advance which numbers are divisible by 3 -- 3,6,9,... -- so increment by 3, not by 1 and skip the need to take remainders.

Answer (score 1):

#### See mine

##### For `n ~= 100,000`, better use `long getSum(int n)`

...and we need to adjust.

Comments inline:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.BitSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Test {
    // Our thread pool (e.g...):
    static final ExecutorService THREAD_POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    // to complete our "tasks" (see javadoc):
    static final ExecutorCompletionService<BitSet> ECS = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(THREAD_POOL);

    static long getSum(int n) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException { // for brevity: throw
        // start "3 job":
        ECS.submit(() -> findDivisors(3, n));
        // start "5 job":
        ECS.submit(() -> findDivisors(5, n));
        // start "7 job":
        ECS.submit(() -> findDivisors(7, n));

        // collect result:
        BitSet collect = new BitSet(n + 1);
        for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) { // complete all jobs ...
            BitSet tmpResult = ECS.take().get(); // see javadoc
            if (tmpResult != null) // "or'ing" their results into "collect":
                collect.or(tmpResult);
        }

        // stream over "all set indices" in "collect" and return ...
        return collect.stream()
                // ... (as a long;) their sum 
                .mapToLong(i -> (long) i).sum();
    }

    static BitSet findDivisors(int d, int n) { // MAIN JOB:
        BitSet mem = new BitSet(n + 1); // ignore 0th bit
        for (int i = d; i <= n; i += d) { // set i(th) index to true:
            mem.set(i);
        }
        return mem; // done!
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // do I/O, more tests...:
        System.out.println(getSum(10));
        System.out.println(getSum(100));
        System.out.println(getSum(1_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(10_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(100_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(1_000_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(10_000_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(100_000_000));
        System.out.println(getSum(1_000_000_000));
        // System.out.println(getSum(2_000_000_000)); // oh-oh
        // finally: release resources:
        THREAD_POOL.shutdown();
    }
}
```

##### Prints:

```text
40
2838
272066
27152139
2714364277
271428928569
27142867857145
2714285835714288
271428572071428566
1085714285285714288 # ?? <- this looks like (long!) overflow ;(
```

#### References

- [`ExecutorCompletionService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) + linked (since java 1.5)
- [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) (since java 1.0;)
- [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)
- [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

#### Key Points

- BitSet as "data structure":

  - similar to `boolean[]([])`, but:

    - better memory efficience (a `boolean` costs 1 byte of memory (in current hw architecture), whereas BitSet can do better (backed by a `long[]|byte[]`))
    - advanced API (`or, and, xor, cardinality, stream, ...`)
  - to overcome its lack of multi-thread support we can:

    - "synchronize"
    - use multiple BitSets to join/or/and/... them together
- `i`th index in bitSet_x (3/5/7) set, means: `i` is divisible by x (3/5/7)
- challenges start from `n~=100000`

---

And the "ultra-light" version (regarding the lines of code, performance is another chapter), inspired by Andrey B.P.:

```java
[static] long getSum(int n) {
  return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, n) // rangeClosed not range (or +/-1;)
    .parallel() // ok
    .filter(i ->
         (i % 3 == 0 && i % 15 > 0 && i % 21 > 0) // 1.
      || (i % 5 == 0 && i % 35 > 0) // 2.
      || (i % 7 == 0) // 3.
    )
    .mapToLong(i -> (long) i) // for bigger input
    .sum(); // #
}
```

Comment: upvoted this solution. It is a handy solution for this kind of task.

Comment: that is not a big deal to write "ultra-fast" as well :)

Comment: Actually the ultra-light will be light-years-faster than the "normal" solution.

Comment: Also Andrey's code is shorter and better. It should just use a LongStream instead of IntStream and would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

When your goal is to parallelize computations you should make sure that your solution is actually faster than a serial (single threaded) one. Unfortunately your code (fixed by Mukhtar Amirkhanov) is probably much slower than a naive loop going through 1 to n. This is because a naive solution does not have to store the actual dividends anywhere. Also your multithreaded program synchronizes on each step, which means it won't actually make much progress in parallel. Finally, after the threads join your program removes duplicates in the main thread - that step alone take probably way more time than the naive loop.

Unfortunately, the task is poorly defined, because the fastest solution is just a formula (as shown by @Andrey B. Panfilov) which can be computed in constant time `O(1)` and which cannot be sped up by multithreading. Probably your teacher meant to speed the computations by using multithreading compared to the naive solution, so you should settle for "second-best" approach.

A meaningful approach to parallelizing such tasks is described by @Mike Nakis in his answer. You should split the work between threads not by the divisor, but by ranges of dividends. You can define separate threads do the work, and after joining them just add their results, or you can simply use a parallel stream (as shown by @Andrey B. Panfilov in a comment, just use a LongStream instead of an IntStream) to the same effect (if streams are allowed in your assignment).

```
import java.util.*;
public class FindMultiples
{
  public static final int numberOfThreads = 3;
  public static long[] partialResults = new long[numberOfThreads];

  public static class MyThread implements Runnable{
    public int threadNumber;
    public int n;

    public MyThread(int threadNumber, int n) {
        this.threadNumber = threadNumber;
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int start = ((threadNumber - 1) * n / numberOfThreads) + 1;
        int end = threadNumber * n / numberOfThreads;
        long result = 0;
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)
                result += i;
        partialResults[threadNumber - 1] = result;
    }
  }

  public long getSum(int n) {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[numberOfThreads];
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++)
        threads[i - 1] = new Thread(new MyThread(i, n));

    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++)
        threads[i - 1].start();

    try {
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++)
            threads[i - 1].join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    long sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfThreads; i++)
        sum += partialResults[i - 1];

    return sum;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FindMultiples findMultiples = new FindMultiples();
    System.out.println(findMultiples.getSum(1000));
  }
}
```